# .Net windows service deployment and pass token to service while installing

Tags: windows-services, installshield, setup-deployment

I have created a `windows service`.Which runs every 5 minute once. I need to start this windows service with a `token`.

So for that i have created `setup.exe` using the `Installshield` limited edition. When user installs windows service i need to pass token to windows service then the service uses that token to get the details from API. So each user will get separate token then install and start the service. Need help on the following

1. Is there any way to  pass the token when installing the `setup.exe`?
2. Adding auto update feature to windows service installation in `installshiled`

Comment: Does "pass a token" in the context of the service mean the same as passing the string on the command line to the service exe?

Comment: Yes Its something like sc start ServiceName token123456789